# Init a new project of react native fails

Tags: npm, react-native

I just started with React Native with Mac OS, but unfortunately, the init of a new project failed. It somehow hangs:

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/dickyjohan/Documents/Xcode Workspace/AwesomeProject
npm WARN engine stacktrace-parser@0.1.1: wanted: {"node":"~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.7.5"})

> ws@0.4.31 install /Users/dickyjohan/Documents/Xcode Workspace/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

-
```

I thought it has a problem with ruby, but I have updated my ruby to the latest ruby 2.2.1p85. Does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Still happens to me. Did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: Yes still does. I ended up just taking another existing project and modify it to my needs.

Comment: As 3(!) deleted(!) answers say, the solution for me was to simply wait way longer than you'd expect. As in, 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Trying installing node-gyp before:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Comment: I mean if the installation of node-gyp went through

Comment: Yes the node-gyp installation is successful, but I still ended up with the same error as above, (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0) hanging

Answer (score 0):

The depended package 'ws' has a wrong version,change it in package.json of react-native and try again.good luck!